# Get Current Path to Script within AppleScript and Append Subdirectory

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript that I would like to be able to use from anywhere in the file system.  Currently, it has some paths which are hardcoded, so it runs only from the Downloads folder.  How should I go about getting the current path to the AppleScript and then appending a subdirectory to that path once obtained?

Setting the current path to the script as a variable would be preferable (perhaps current_path).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the path of the current script with `path to me`.
Extracting the path to the *directory* containing the script is slightly tricky:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set current_path to container of (path to me) as alias
end tell
```

Comment: If posix path is needed add the following command before `end tell` : `set p to POSIX path of current_path`

Comment: This worked for me to get the app's path and append a subdirectory; `set current_path to (POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as alias)) & "subdirectory/"`

Answer (score 2):

'alias' gave me an error.
This worked for me

```
set my_POSIX_path to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```