# Finding file in parent folder of an AppleScript

Tags: applescript, command-line, script, path

I have an AppleScript that calls another script (a perl script in this case) which resides in the same folder as the AppleScript.
Now I'm trying to put the script into a variable like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set scriptPath to POSIX path of (container of (path to me) as text)
    set perlScript to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of scriptPath & " -name myscript.pl")
end tell
```

But the result that I get from the find shell command has two slashes before the file name: `/path/to/folder//myscript.pl`
Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
While I don't quite understand the double slash I managed to resolve the problem by not invoking the Finder at all and doing the following:

```
set scriptPath to POSIX path of (path to me) -- path to AppleScript
set scriptFolder to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of scriptPath -- path to folder with AppleScript
set perlScript to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of scriptFolder & " -name myscript.pl") -- path to PerlScript
```

Don't know if that's the best way to do it but it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to get right the pathname of `..` from AppleScript:

[Get Current Path to Script within AppleScript and Append Subdirectory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107204/22003)

Anyway, the actual construct you got: `/path/to/folder//myscript.pl`
is a correct pathname to your Perl script. The 1st `/` is coming from the terminal one coming from `container`: `/path/to/folder/`.

Hence your built find command is very similar to this one you might try
to experiment:

```
find ~/ -name "Documents" -print
```

Hint: work directly in Perl, it is many times more efficient than any AppleScript.

Comment: I had looked at that answer but it gives me a `Can’t make quoted form of alias "Macintosh HD:path:to:folder:" into type Unicode text.` error.  I am trying to incorporate the perlscript into an applescript because I want to eventually set up a watched folder ... I wouldn't know how to do that with perl directly.  -- But you say that the `/path/to/folder//myscript.pl` form is correct?  Why the two slashes?

Comment: It actually does work with the two slashes!  True (but funny).    As does your other solution.  I resolved it differently, however (see edits), looks "prettier" to me (but I don't know whether it could run into other problems).